# How to get a user object in Praw?

Tags: python, praw

I'm attempting to find the user of Reddit so I can iterate through their last comments, weird reason but I'm in need of getting the user's object.

Cannot find in the docs where there's a way to get a user via username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import praw 

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxxxxxxx',
                     client_secret='xxxxxxxx', 
                     password='xxxxxxxxx',
                     user_agent='xxxxxxx',
                     username='xxxxxxxx')

user = reddit.redditor('username')
```

> https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/redditor.html